# How to upload web.config file using WebDAV on IIS7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, webdav

I want to copy an ASP.NET MVC website to a remote IIS 7 server using WebDAV. I have created a site in IIS, enabled WebDAV and assigned a special application pool I have named "WebDAV Application Pool". Using a Windows 7 or Vista client I'm able to mount the remote site as a network drive. So far, so good.

However, I have problems uploading `web.config` files to the remote site. One problem is that as soon as a `web.config` has been uploaded it is used to configure the WebDAV site. The `web.config` file in a `Views` folder of a MVC project effectively blocks access to that folder.

To work around this problem I have configured the application pool in the `applicationHost.config` file:

```
<configuration>
  <applicationPools>
    <add name="WebDAV Application Pool"
       autoStart="true"
       enableConfigurationOverride="false" />
  </applicationPools>
</configuration>
```

The interesting part is the 'enableConfigurationOverride` attribute:

> When **true**, indicates that delegated settings in Web.config files will processed for applications within this application pool. When **false**, all settings in Web.config files will be ignored for this application pool.

Doing this makes it possible to upload a `web.config` file to the `Views` folder without breaking access to the folder.

However, I'm still unable to upload a `web.config` file to the root folder. I have the following settings in the `applicationHost.config` file to ensure that request filtering doesn't interfere with WebDAV:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="webdav.mysite.tld">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <fileExtensions applyToWebDAV="false" />
          <verbs applyToWebDAV="false" />
          <hiddenSegments applyToWebDAV="false" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

In particular `hiddenSegments` will normally block access to `web.config` but setting the `applyToWebDAV` attribute to **false** should ensure that this file isn't blocked when using WebDAV.

Unfortunately, I'm still unable to copy my `web.config` file to the root folder of the site. Doing drag and drop in Windows Explorer to the mapped WebDAV network drive will result in the following error message:

> Error 0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.

On the wire it seems that the HTTP status `400 Bad Request` is returned.

Is there anything I can do to configure WebDAV on IIS 7 to avoid this problem?

---

### Followup

Currently I'm unable to reproduce the problem I described above. Perhaps I had to restart something or some other unknown factor fixed my problem. The bottom line is that I now can publish a web site using WebDAV.

Comment: Your bit about `enableConfigurationOverride` is invaluable. I can't believe that isn't a setting that is accessible from the GUI anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

1) Open up `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\schema\WEBDAV_schema`

2) Add the following inside of the `configSchema` section

```
<sectionSchema name="system.codedom">
  <element name="compilers">
    <collection addElement="compiler" removeElement="remove" clearElement"clear">
      <attribute name="language" type="string" isCombinedKey="true"/>
      <attribute name="extension" type="string" isCombinedKey="true"/>
      <attribute name="type" type="string"/>
      <attribute name="warningLevel" type="int"/>
      <collection addElement="providerOption">
        <attribute name="name" type="string" isUniqueKey="true"/>
        <attribute name="value" type="string"/>
      </collection>
    </collection>
  </element>
</sectionSchema>
```

Comment: sorry for it being an image, but for some reason the editor was stripping out the xml if I pasted it in there.

Comment: What is the purpose of modifying the schema? Anyway, it seems that my problem has vanished.

Comment: Bit of invalid XML here, too small to edit. clearElement"clear" should be clearElement="clear".